# What is the Cocoa/OSX equivalent of wglMakeCurrent or glXMakeCurrent?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, opengl

I understand that Cocoa requires that windows be created/managed on the main thread. So, I'd like to have two or three windows with unique contexts, but I'd really prefer to draw to each of them from separate threads. Plus, a little bit of Google searching seems to indicate that rapidly context-switching on one thread is pretty expensive/slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the [CGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html) interface for fast context switching, specifically: `CGLSetCurrentContext`. However, it may be more consistent to use the `makeCurrentContext` method for [NSOpenGLContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004074) in a Cocoa application.

Comment: I suspect this is indeed what I am looking for. Do you know if, like other operating systems, OSX lets the OpenGL rendering take place on some other thread? I am simply trying to reconcile this with the fact that Cocoa requires the windows themselves on the main thread.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw - I believe it's fine as long as rendering calls are serialized.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. Thanks so much.